# Need a conditional to test if title of parent page matches title of child page

Tags: loop, templates, conditional-tags, children

In my main loop, I need to incorporate proper html markup into a  conditional to test if title of parent page matches title of child page and do (or do not) display certain content. Default might be to keep h1 tag , otherwise do not display.

```
<!-- basic loop -->
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post() ; ?>
<h2> 
    <?php $parent_title = get_the_title($post->post_parent); echo $parent_title; ?>
</h2>

<?php
$children = get_pages('child_of='.$post->ID);
if( count( $children ) != 0 ) { 

echo 'NO children';

}
else { echo 'has children';}
?>


    <h1 style="margin-bottom:12px"><?php the_title(); ?></h1> 
    <?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

ex) I want h1 to show here...
http://howlingwolfmedia.com/site3/my-club/facilities/

but not here:
http://howlingwolfmedia.com/site3/my-club/

**solution here as function:**

```
function testchildren () { 
   global $post; 
    $childtest = get_pages('child_of='.$post->ID); 
       if( count( $childtest ) != 0 ) { 
       return false; 
       } else { 
       return true; 
      } 
}
```

**and implementation as markup:**

```
   <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post() ; ?> 
       <h2><?php $parent_title = get_the_title($post->post_parent); echo $parent_title; ?> </h2>
    <?php if ( testchildren() ) : ?> 
        <h1 style="margin-top:6px; margin-bottom:12px;"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Comment: What is the question exactly? You have the parent title. Just compare it to the child.

Comment: I created a function called testchildren...
`
function testchildren () {
   global $post;
 $childtest = get_pages('child_of='.$post->ID); 
 if( count( $childtest ) != 0 )  {
  return false;
  }
 else
  {
  return true;
  }
}`
and html markup:
`<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post() ; ?>
 <h2><?php $parent_title = get_the_title($post->post_parent); echo $parent_title; ?>
 </h2>
 <?php if ( testchildren() ) : ?>
    <h1 style="margin-top:6px; margin-bottom:12px;"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
 <?php endif; ?>


 <?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>`

Comment: Please [edit] that code into the question.

Comment: I added backticks per instructions and that's how it formatted. See function here: http://pastebin.com/PBJjtXuG and implementation here: http://pastebin.com/98MJCWLg

Comment: I didn't ask you to format the comment. I asked you to edit the comment into the question. Code formatting in comments is very minimal.

Comment: OK. Solution has been added to the initial question.

Comment: Sorry. If that is a solution, it should be posted as an answer in the answer box below. Your comment above did not state that the code was a solution.

Answer (score 0):

**solution here as function:**

```
function testchildren () { 
   global $post; 
    $childtest = get_pages('child_of='.$post->ID); 
       if( count( $childtest ) != 0 ) { 
       return false; 
       } else { 
       return true; 
      } 
}
```

**and implementation as markup:**

```
   <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post() ; ?> 
       <h2><?php $parent_title = get_the_title($post->post_parent); echo $parent_title; ?> </h2>
    <?php if ( testchildren() ) : ?> 
        <h1 style="margin-top:6px; margin-bottom:12px;"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```